# Can I view the runtime structure of a dynamic in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic-language-runtime

I just ran across an interesting error caused by a misconfiguration in my application, and it prompted this question.

**The Error in Question**

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC 3 web application, and I had accidentally dragged the web.config file into itself from solution explorer, resulting in the following in web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="trueD:\Projects\app_base\src\WebApp.UI\Web.config"/>
</appSettings>
```

What was happening was that this configuration caused the ViewContext object to be corrupted (and rightly so); I got the following when the MVC runtime tried to access it (this from the immediate window)

```
? ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled
    'ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled' threw an exception of type 'System.FormatException'
    base {System.SystemException}: {"String was not recognized as a valid Boolean."}
```

**My Question**

Is there a way to look at the contents *of memory* for a `dynamic` in the DLR?  In this case, I'd like to see the contents of the memory location that is referenced to parse `ClientValidationEnabled`, but every time I tried to access the value, the runtime automatically attempted to box it into a `bool`.  I got as far as

```
((dynamic)((dynamic)this).ViewContext).ClientValidationEnabled
```

before I gave up trying to figure out a QuickWatch way to do it.

Comment: What you should do in this context is just set a breakpoint in the getter for `ClientValidationEnabled` and see what code it's executing to return the value. It's hard to imagine what your model of `dynamic` is, but it doesn't make sense to look at the contents of its memory.

Comment: `ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled` is part of the MVC3 runtime; I've looked at the MVC3 code and the getter just makes a call down into (eventually) the `HttpContext` cache.  What I'm asking about is a way to inspect the `Dictionary` (for lack of a better term) that backs a `dynamic` in memory.

Comment: There's no reason to expect that a `dynamic` will have its properties backed by *anything*, let alone in memory, let alone a dictionary. For all you know, it could be reading the value straight from the config file on disk whenever you ask for it.

Comment: That's a very good point; from that point of view I can certainly see how there would be no catch-all way to view it.  Would you mind writing up an answer to that effect?

Comment: Straight from the disk? I haven't done much of anything low-level since college, but it seems like if the process is going to work with some data, it's going to load that data into its address space in memory. At which point you could, in theory, hunt it down with a tool like windbg or sos (both of which I know little more than their names), right?

Comment: @joelt - that's the sort of answer I'm looking for, but without knowing much at all about how those tools work or what sort of effort is involved in moving that route, I can't answer your question :)

Comment: However, Gabe's comments are generally correct (and a general answer is what I was seeking) - at the end of the day, a property is still a method, and while it's entirely possible for it to be backed by a field, it's equally as likely that it's getting the returned value off the disk, or the network, and debugging into the execution is the only way to watch that process.